# Sanitize searchable string JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to make it possible searching for a string with extra character, which should be removed before shooting find function.

E.g.
Search string is "John", while I want to get returned all possible variations with "^" within it (J^ohn, Jo^hn, Joh^n, ^John, John^) as correct ones.

JS part:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#search').keyup(function()
    {
        searchTable($(this).val());
    });
});

function searchTable(inputVal)
{
    var table = $('#tblData');
    table.find('tr').each(function(index, row)
    {
        var allCells = $(row).find('td');
        if(allCells.length > 0)
    {
        var found = false;
        allCells.each(function(index, td)
        {
            var regExp = new RegExp(inputVal, 'i');
            if(regExp.test($(td).text()))
            {
                found = true;
                return false;
            }
        });
        if(found == true)$(row).show();else $(row).hide();
    }
});
}
```

HTML part:

```
    <div class="tables">
<p>
    <label for="search">
        <strong>Enter name</strong>
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="search"/>
    <label></label>
</p>
<table id="tblData" class="target table table-bordered table-striped">
   <tr>
       <th>First Name</th>
       <th>Last Name</th>
       <th>number</th>
       <th>letters</th>
       <th>Gender</th>
       <th>Company</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>Jo^hn</td>
       <td>Lenno^n</td>
       <td>151</td>
       <td>sf</td>
       <td>Male</td>
       <td>SMS Global (Technologies)</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>Pau^l</td>
       <td>McC^artney</td>
       <td>753</td>
       <td>tj</td>
       <td>Male</td>
       <td>SMS Global (Services)</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>George</td>
       <td>Harrison</td>
       <td>24</td>
       <td>ge</td>
       <td>Female</td>
       <td>SMS AIM Technologies</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>Ringo</td>
       <td>Starr</td>
       <td>26</td>
       <td>hg</td>
       <td>Female</td>
       <td>SMS Global (Help Desk)</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Here is example:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaga/ck5gkcdj/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can replace all **"^"** and try compare the input string with data as below.

```
var inputString="jOhn";
inputString=inputString.toLowerCase();
var text="jOH^n";
text=text.toLowerCase();
text=text.replace("^","");
(text===inputString)?true:false;
```

If you want to use **text similarity** then you can use any text similarity algorithms such as [Levenshtein string matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm, for quick solution try this library: [fuzzyset](http://glench.github.io/fuzzyset.js/)

Comment: Case is I get table filled up dynamic and I want ^ to visible in the table, on the other hand I need to keep the ability searching for the string without ^, but retain results with ^.